# Invalid procedure call or argument in excel VBA , and it worked well before until now

Tags: excel, vba

I used the following code for a while and it worked well till now.
Suddenly, it showed "Invalid procedure call or argument" when I tried to open this file.

```
Function IP(x, xr, yr)
    IP = (Application.Index(yr, Application.Match(x, xr, 1)) + (x - Application.Index(xr, Application.Match(x, xr, 1))) * (Application.Index(yr, Application.Match(x, xr, 1) + 1) - Application.Index(yr, Application.Match(x, xr, 1))) / (Application.Index(xr, Application.Match(x, xr, 1) + 1) - Application.Index(xr, Application.Match(x, xr, 1))))
End Function
```

Does anyone know what happened to my file?

I tried to delete all of code and save it, but it still does not allow me to save my file.

Comment: If you separate all those Index/Matches out (saving each "answer" as a variable), and then adding, etc.  does it still throw the error?

Comment: Is this used as a UDF? What type of variables are `x`, `xr`, and `yr`? What is the expected result (`IP`)?

Comment: Yes, this is a UDF. This function is interpolation function. x is a value between xr (a range) and yr is corresponding range. @VBasic2008

Comment: @BruceWayne I will try this today, thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. VBA code I have been running for years suddenly failed today with this error. mid-day with no visible updates.

```
quoteindex = Application.Match(stkcode, Application.Index(ary_quotes, , 1), 0)
```

The (variable) data in my array has exceeded some kb limit. In my case this error has suddenly been caused by too much data in the array. (2050x42).  If reduce the number of columns in the array by excluding data columns I am not using the code works again. So maybe worthwhile using a small dataset for initial troubleshooting.

Comment: "_Not sure why I am being downvoted._" - Don't be discouraged - take it as an opportunity to learn a bit more about how this site works. The first version of your answer was [not actually an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - it was basically a "me too!" comment. The second version was also not an answer - it was a thought on what the problem _might be_. After some more time (enough time for the answer to attract downvotes), you posted an edit containing tangible information relating to the problem and its possible cause.

Comment: I cannot be sure, but I suspect you would have avoided downvotes if you had _only_ posted the information in the "EDIT" paragraph (and none of the other content) - perhaps accompanied by a code fragment illustrating the specifics of your findings. See also [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)